# Bitbucket - "clone" activity log

Tags: bitbucket

I invited some folks to my private repo on Bitbucket for the first time. Will I see it when they have cloned the repo? Is this type of activity listed in the Recent Activity column?

Answer (score 0):

No such feature available till now. Bitbucket support audit log for

- Basic account information (name, location, website) updates
- Changes to email addresses
- Links with third party accounts (Google, Twitter, Facebook)
- Addition of OAuth services integrations
- Groups & general access list changes
- Creation and deletion of repositories

In addition, we also record the IP address associated with the change so you’ll know exactly where the change has come from.

[Official Resource](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/08/15/new-audit-logs-give-you-the-who-what-when-and-where/)